# Executing python script from SQL Server agent job getting error

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I am new to python.  I am using Python 3 and I am trying to execute a PYTHON script via a .bat file in my SQL Server 2016 Agent job but getting an error.  ALL files, the .bat, .csv files and the .py files all sit in the SAME share directory.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my what is in my .bat file:

```
python \\abicfs2\shared\dev\DATAEXPORT\MonthlyReports\combineCSVFiles.py
```

Here is the code in the combineCSVFiles.py file:

```
import os

filename0 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname("BoundPoliciesAddedAtFaultEndorsementWithin10Days_Combined.csv"))
filename1 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname("BoundPoliciesAddedAtFaultEndorsementWithin10Days_Counts.csv"))
filename2 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname("BoundPoliciesAddedAtFaultEndorsementWithin10Days_Details.csv"))
f = open(filename0, "w+")
f.close()
fin1 = open(filename1, "r")
data1 = fin1.read()
fin1.close()
fin2 = open(filename2, "r")
data2 = fin2.read()
fin2.close()
fout = open(filename0, "a")
fout.write(data1)
fout.write(data2)
fout.close()
```

Here is the error I'm getting in the SQL Server agent job:

> Message Executed as user: domain\sqlsvcAA.
>   C:\Windows\system32>python
>   \abicfs2\shared\dev\DATAEXPORT\MonthlyReports\combineCSVFiles.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "\abicfs2\shared\dev\DATAEXPORT\MonthlyReports\combineCSVFiles.py",
>   line 9, in       f = open(filename0, "w+")  FileNotFoundError:
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''.  Process Exit Code 1.  The
>   step failed.

Comment: First does it work if you run it from outside the Agent Job?  Try that first.  If it does then could be permissions.  Make sure the user running agent job has the correct permissions to access your paths (a big issue a lot of the times is the permissions because Agent Job runs as specific user.).  Or the SQL Server can not find the path because it is not accessible from the server where the job is running on

Comment: Brad, thanks for the response.  I was able to execute it from my local box without issue and all worked great.  Hopefully our server admin can get this fixed pretty quickly.  I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: If you ran it locally and it worked then it shouldnt be an issue with the script itself (always good to check that first), but one of the above 2 problems are most likely the issue then.